# YII2 get user timezone dynamically

Tags: timezone, yii2

I am using :

```
'timeZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta',
```

to set user timezone. But i need the timezone should be dynamic according to user location.

How can i do that ?

Comment: use [date-default-timezone-get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)